# Name of the jar file for TIBCO JMS palatte?

Tags: java, jms, tibco, tibco-ems

I have installed Tibco AMX BW 5.7.0.
But i could not find **JMS palatte** in the designer.

I also tried reinstalling BW with 5.9.0 version.
I think the jar is missing in both the installables.

Anyone knows **jar file** name **for JMS palatte?**

(Please dont tell like download new installable or abything like that).

Comment: I think I got it...I found JAR named tibcoJMS at tibco\tra\5.5\lib\TIBCOjms.jar!
Will update on this soon....Please share your valuable knowledge if any.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the JMS palette is activated in the Palette Browser (Palettes Menu -> Browse...):

[image]

Comment: Hey, Thanks Tony! Jms palatte was installed with standerdAMX-Bw installation, but was not selected in Palattes Browser.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Good to hear it helps you. If you think my answer worked for you, you can mark it as "accepted"